# Show particular area shaded in MapBox

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapbox

I am using the MapBox iOS SDK for my project. Now I want to show shaded area in the Map for a particular area like any country, any continents etc. So how can I implement this feature.

Your suggestions and response will be helpful.

Comment: you're using mapbox to show offline map?

Answer (score 0):

You can either do this client-side with something like `RMShape` or server-side by either shading things on the Mapbox.com online editor or making a custom map to upload with [TileMill](http://tilemill.com). The Mapbox site has lots of documentation on doing these things.